# VBA calls a c++ dll that uses Intel tbb crahses before entering the function

Tags: c++, vba, tbb

I have a c++ dll that is called by an excel VBA code and works perfectly fine for quite some time.
After I added the tbb library to the same code it crashes before even entering the function being called.

The weird before happens because when I`m on VS2019 I can run the DEBUG or RELEASE version on Local Windows Debugger and it works perfectly fine but if I run it from Excel it crashes.

I did the depency walker and it finds the TBB DLL, any Ideas of whats causing the crash?

Best

Comment: Q: Doctor, it hurts when I do this.  A: Then don't do that.  Lose the TBB  library ;)

Comment: But the performance gain is about 2.5x faster even running on debugging VS